# PHP split email with rules

Tags: php, regex, split, rules

I have to split an email that is received everyday, with a set of rules.
This is an example of the email:

```
A N K U N F T   11.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F882129  dsdsaidsaia
 F882129  xxxyxyagydaysd

**«CUT HERE»**


A N K U N F T   18.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
 11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881554  ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ
 F881554  xcvcxvcxvcvxc
 F881554  xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv

**«CUT HERE»**


11.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2830  14:25   17:50
 18.08.15  xxx  xxx  X3 2831  18:40
 F881605  xczxcdfsfdsdfs
 F881605  zxccxzxzdffdsfds

**«CUT HERE»**
```

So it basically has to be cut whenever the last F999999 appears ( where 9 can be any number). How can I do this?

Comment: read a line, if it starts with `[space]F[digit]`, then skip it, keep skipping until you hit a blank line - boom, done.

Comment: Just split by `\n\n`

Comment: I forgot to say that I found the regex to find each one that is: [F]{1}\d{6}, however the problem is that if that F999999 repeats I should only cut after the laste one and only cut after the text(For example:zxccxzxzdffdsfds) finishes....

Comment: @MiguelSousa if you think that it's an issue when sending the data by post why don't you show us how you do that? how in the hell are we supposed to fix the issue when we can't see how you do it?

Comment: Sorry I didnt think that there was sometthing wrong with the form... It seeams that the newlines are disapearing when I post...

Comment: @MiguelSousa How do you know that the newlines are disappearing? When the page echos, is the regular expression working but the result missing newlines?

Comment: @MiguelSousa also, if the regular expression worked then you need to not unaccept an answer. It did exactly what your original question asked and now you have a new problem that is (if i'm correct) completely unrelated. You need to ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, I unaccepted it by mistake when browsing with cellphone. I have edited this question and added a other question related to this new problem.. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, though splitting on `\n\n` would work as

```
(?:\sF\d+.*?\n\n)\K(\n)
```

Split on the capture group.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rT0yQ1/3)

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answers!! The \n\n might not work becuase sometimes the F999999, are separated with empty lines inbetween.

Comment: Thank you I think this is what I was looking for!!

Comment: Hi, I just noticed the last "F999999" is eliminated and I want it included.. I tried to add a \n to regex but didnt work...