# Regex not working when passing string with post

Tags: php, regex, post, textarea, newline

I need to split a email with some rules as explained here: 
[PHP split email with rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012237/php-split-email-with-rules)

So, I tried the solution on a regex101: https://regex101.com/r/rT0yQ1/1 and it worked, however when I do this on my server with php and pasting the content of email to a textbox and then sending the content by post is doesnt work no more.

Here is my code:

file teste.php:

```
<form method="post" action="teste2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea name="email" cols="110" rows="30" id="email"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Dividir" />
</form>
```

file teste2.php:

```
<?php
    $str = $_POST['email'];
    $re = "/(?:\sF\d+.*?\n\n)(\n)/"; 
    $subst = ">>CUT HERE>>"; 
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
    echo $result;
?>
```

I try this here: https://3v4l.org/mqrJc and it works.
However it seems like a problem when I send the text in a textarea by post, because if I use a string it works. Here is the print of the echo:

It prints this:

```
> A N K U N F T 11.08.15 *** NEUBUCHUNG *** 11.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2830
> 14:25 17:50 18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40 F882129 dsdsaidsaia F882129
> xxxyxyagydaysd A N K U N F T 18.08.15 *** NEUBUCHUNG *** 11.08.15 xxx
> xxx X3 2830 14:25 17:50 18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40 F881554
> ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ F881554 xcvcxvcxvcvxc F881554 xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv
> 11.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2830 14:25 17:50 18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40 F881605 xczxcdfsfdsdfs F881605 zxccxzxzdffdsfds
```

It deletes newlines and even worse >>CUT HERE>> does not appear where it is suposed to...

After using nl2br the output is:

```
A N K U N F T 11.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
11.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2830 14:25 17:50
18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40
F882129 dsdsaidsaia
F882129 xxxyxyagydaysd


A N K U N F T 18.08.15
*** NEUBUCHUNG ***
11.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2830 14:25 17:50
18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40
F881554 ZXCXZCXCXZCCXZ
F881554 xcvcxvcxvcvxc
F881554 xvcxvcxcvxxvccvxxcv


11.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2830 14:25 17:50
18.08.15 xxx xxx X3 2831 18:40
F881605 xczxcdfsfdsdfs
F881605 zxccxzxzdffdsfds
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your echo issue is just a simple mistake is displaying the result on a webbrowser. Change the last line from `echo $result;` to `echo nl2br($result);`

`nl2br()` is a function in php that converts newline characters into `<br/>` which will show up properly in a webbrowser

Try the following for the updated regular expression. Your newlines are not `\n`, they are `\r\n` so that's all we're changing.

```
(?:\sF\d+.*?\r\n\r\n)(\r\n)
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/M37Jk)

Comment: Correct, however the regex isnt working because >>CUT HERE>>  doesnt not appear where it is suposed to. And works at: https://3v4l.org/mqrJc

Comment: @MiguelSousa can you show the new output after you used nl2br? it'll help. Trust me.

Comment: Edited the question with output. Can test directly here: http://louros.webmadeira.net/teste/teste.php

Comment: @MiguelSousa aha! I figured that this was the bug :)

You don't have single `\n` in that string, you have `\r\n`

Comment: Ah! Thanks alot! I chamged regex to: "/(?:\sF\d+.*?\r\n\r\n)(\r\n)/" and worked!